# How robust is nodejs as an http server?

Tags: javascript, security, http, node.js

If I use the http module of nodejs to make a simple http server, how much validation/checking do I have to do?

Does the module take care of security issues like malformed requests and requests with malicious header values?  Does the module ensure that everything follows the http spec, or do I have to do a lot of checking to make sure that my server isn't easy to crash?

**Edit: Let's say nodejs doesn't do any real validation, which I'm pretty sure is the case.  What do I have to do to make sure my server isn't easily crashable?**

Comment: [http module source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js)

Comment: @Raynos: it looks like it does practically no validation at all, just parses the request into the headers and body.  Do you agree?

Comment: I don't know anything about HTTP server security / loopholes or hacking. So I can't comment on _what_ it should validate.

Comment: @Edit ideally nothing. In practice there may be N unknown vulnerabilities. The problem is that their are not well known and there isn't much you can do apart from guess. pragmatically I havn't noticed anyone recommending shielding / guarding practices in the node community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a malicious header value? Node is low level, so a lot of things aren't checked. But you have to look at those things. But it isn't like someone can send "execute 0xFA894224" or something. The only holes it's likely to have are things like allowing malformed request (eg, maybe you might get `request.location: "\*\*\* CHINAAA \*\*\*"`, forgetting to launch a socket close event, or throwing a JavaScript error and gracefully terminating.

You can always check yourself for these things, or use a try catch block, process.on, etc. Of course, it's not to say there might not be a buffer overflow or something somewhere, but it is unlikely considering node is built on top of v8, and many of the libraries are pure JavaScript

Edit:
How to stop random crashes:

```
process.on('uncaughtException',function() {
 /* ignore error */
});
```

Comment: Also, although this will stop 99% of random crashes, 99% of random crashes are caused by JavaScript, not node. For example, you might do obj[request.location] = request.headers, which might crash if someone managed to slip '\_\_proto\_\_' in there somehow.
This is just general JavaScript considerations however.

Comment: For the record '/* ignore error */' is a very stupid idea. If you implement it, please replace it with some sensible error handling.

Answer (score -1):

NodeJS wasn't made to be used as a world-facing HTTP server. It's HTTP capabilities can, however, be used to proxy requests to a proper web server.

Off-topic, but Nginx is really good at doing this, as it holds a steady-ish number of threads.

Comment: So it's a bad idea in general to service POST and GET requests directly using a nodejs server?

Comment: The most common setup I've heard of is using Nginx as a gateway to one or more node.js instances. I don't think it's correct to say that it "wasn't made to be..." when it isn't done being made. The developers of the project seem to be gunning for a web-facing application server, to me.

Comment: Node can launch more node processes, imho, using nginx is not useful.